# Namespaces and mountpoints

Tags: linux

There's a way to create hidden mount points if the root user unshares the current namespace and mounts directories without updating mtab. Is there a easy way of listing this without having to filter through the proc file system?

Comment: have you got an example of this? what are the commands involved?  I find that both `mount` and `findmnt` will report all mounts.

Comment: @Jasen: `unshare --mount --propagation=slave`, it's what containers like Docker use.

Answer (score 2):

> There's a way to create hidden mount points if the root user unshares the current namespace and mounts directories without updating mtab. Is there a easy way of listing this without having to filter through the proc file system?

First of all, `/proc` **is** the primary way of accessing current mount information on Linux.

Many modern Linux distributions *never* update mtab; it is simply a symlink to `/proc/self/mounts`. (Both the ability to unshare mount namespaces, as well as hiding mounts by "forgetting" to update mtab, are primary reasons for this change. And of course, what's the point of repeating the work that the kernel already does?)

Likewise, the namespace identifiers themselves are *only* exposed via `/proc/$PID/ns/mnt`. There is no other way of checking which processes are in separate namespaces from the main one.

So with that said, the quickest way to list *all* mounts is `cat /proc/*/mounts`. But if you don't want to do that, **util-linux v2.28** introduces the **lsns** tool which can quickly list all unique namespaces as well as their "first" process:

```
$ sudo lsns --type=mnt
        NS TYPE NPROCS    PID USER   COMMAND
4026531840 mnt     300      1 root   /sbin/init
4026531860 mnt       1     38 root   kdevtmpfs
4026532247 mnt       1    271 root   /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd
4026532359 mnt       2    524 root   /usr/bin/NetworkManager --no-daemon
4026532369 mnt       2 267304 root   nginx: master process /usr/bin/nginx -g pid /run/nginx.pid
4026532557 mnt       1    892 colord /usr/lib/colord
```

And once you have the process ID, you can see its mount table using:

```
$ sudo findmnt --tab=/proc/267304/mountinfo
```

(You should always use the `/proc/$PID/mountinfo` file, as it contains a bit more information than `mounts` or /etc/mtab. For example, it describes the actual hierarchy when mounts overlap in unexpected ways, and it more accurately reports the 'source' of a bind mount when it's a file or subdirectory.)

As for a single tool that would simply show what mounts are "missing" from the main namespace – I don't know of any. (One doesn't come with coreutils or util-linux right now, though it shouldn't be difficult to write one if you allow it to dig through /proc.)

Comment: Hmmm it turns out that whenever I run firefox, my version of lsns doesn't display anything. I've since replaced that with another lsns from the linux-util github.